# Beautiful Soup renders only a portion of the page

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to scrape fantasy player data from this website: http://www.footywire.com/. As an example page, I shall refer to this one: http://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/pu-gold-coast-suns--gary-jnr-ablett.

My efforts using BeautifulSoup have unfortunately not yielded positive results. So far, it seems to only render the menu on the left side of the page, and nothing in the middle (being the 2016 Supercoach stats and Breakeven Analysis) for me to actually scrape.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = urllib.urlopen('http://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/pu-gold-coast-suns--gary-jnr-ablett').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
print soup.prettify()
```

Screengrab:
[image]

Where am I going wrong, or what do I need to adjust to get to the stats data that I'm after?

**EDIT:** Following the quick discussion with @Padraic Cunningham, I have determined that the issue specifically seems to be that when executing the BeautifulSoup(r) command, the resultant output is not as full as what is contained in r by itself.

Comment: I cannot replicate using every parser, what version of bs4 are you using?

Comment: I believe it is 4.4.1 in Python 2.7.11

Comment: What parsers do you have installed?

Comment: err....I haven't installed any others, so I guess I'm just using the default one...

Comment: Are you sure the problem is bs4 what does urllib return?

Comment: I'm not. But when I run the code posted, going through the 'prettify' output only results in everything in the menu on the left.

Comment: Print what urllib returns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116028/discussion-between-albort-and-padraic-cunningham).

Comment: I can see that it is outputting the entire page. I've spotted some of the data that I eventually want to scrape

Comment: You sure this isn't loaded via ajax?

Comment: Yeah. I managed to get it going without actually changing anything. I have no genuine idea what I did. But I'm just leaving that bit of code alone so i dont break it